# solr internationalization for performance

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

Currently we use Apache Solr to index English language data. There are over 60 million documents that we index. In addition to English, we will are in process to index data in 20 additional languages. The main requirement here being search across all languages and not just one language. The search field name should remain the same. 
We have come up with 2 main designs -

1. **Option 1 :** Index language data into it's own collection. for e.g. collection_1_en, collection_1_de . Then search across collections . Here we have control over the analyzers used.
2. **Option 2 :** Use a single collection, Declare an new field in schema.xml say name_en, name_de etc and then use copyfield to copy the value OR. programmatically determine the language(using language code) and add it to appropriate field

Which one would be the best approach w.r.t Performance? or is there a better approach to handle this scenario.
**EDIT** : Here data is not translated. i.e field_en data is not a translation of field_de e.g. names of people, company etc.